# Cordova 3.3.1 FileTransfer in Background

Tags: jquery, cordova, file-transfer

I have been having issues with filetransfer downloads failing when the on/off button is pressed. When the user unlocks the device the download hangs and won't continue. Here are the error messages returned:

```
File Transfer Error: The network connection was lost.

FileTransferError {
    body = "";
    code = 3;
    "http_status" = 200;
    source = "some.mp3";
    target = "blah/blah";
}
```

I read [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2190) about a possible fix for this and tried using their CDVFileTransfer.h and .m but I still had the same error occur when the on/off button was pressed.

Anyone have a suggestion about what I can do here? Not being able to download files in the background of the app I am building would be a rather annoying bug, aha.